# Loading small pieces of data with many subscriptions in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a question about Collections - specifically, I want to have a large collection on a server, and load only small bits of it a piece at a time, in an unpredictable order, where I might stop wanting to have a local copy of any given piece at any time. Should I make a new subscription for each piece of data, and then stop it when I no longer want that piece of data? Or should I use some other method? Or should I just load large chunks of it that I won't use and leave them sitting around in my local copy of the collection?

Edit: Or should I have one subscription with a list of the ID's for each piece of data I want, and have the publication function specifically find each of those? Seems complicated, but it does keep me with only having to deal with one subscription.

Edit: Or maybe I should just skip using publications and subscriptions, and just use Methods to pass my data to the client? Loses a lot of functionality, and requires some extra work, but it does dodge most of the problems and should work just fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  Mongo collection ="items"
          {
            name:'item1',
            type:'basic',
            qty:40
           }

you define collections on the Meteor server with

```
Items= new Mongo.Collection('items')
```

1.These collections contain all the data from the MongoDB collections, and you can run Items.find({...}) on them, which will return a **cursor** (a set of records, with methods to iterate through them and return them).

```
Meteor.publish('itemOver30', function itemPublication() {
 return(Items.find({qty:{gte:10},{name:1,qty:1}));
 });
```

This will return cursor to all the records with item qty over 30 in items collection(subset of total records, not whole collection).

2.Cursor is used to publish (send) a set of records (called a "record set"). You can optionally publish only some fields from those records. It is record sets (not collections) that clients subscribe to.

```
Meteor.subscribe('itemOver30');
```

3. On the client, you have Minimongo collections that partially mirror some of the records from the server. "Partially" because they may contain only some of the fields, and "some of the records" because you usually want to send to the client only the records it needs, to speed up page load, and only those it needs and has permission to access.

Comment: I know how subscriptions and publications work, my question is about how I should use them. I want to load items individually, and then drop them individually. Should I use a single subscription with a list of the relevant ID's, or make a new subscription for each one, or skip out on subscriptions entirely and use methods, or do something else...?

Comment: Please give some sample example or code and tell us what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to you, I hadn't noticed your comment. In answer, I'm making a forum, where each post can be in response to any number of other posts and have any number of other posts in response to it, and users can dynamically load and close individual posts in any order they please.